# converting date to string and back to date in java

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, date, simpledateformat

In my program I am trying to convert the date to string to specified format and then back to date. I need the date to be in dd-MMM-yy format. So, I am converting the date to dd-MMM-yy format using SimpleDateFormat like,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
String bookingDate = sdf.format(myDate);
```

The result is what I expected, that is 23-May-12 but when I convert the string back to date 
using parse(), it is changing to Wed May 23 13:16:14 IST 2012.

Is there any way to convert the string back to date without changing format? I strictly need to pass the date object in the specified format to the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when i convert the string back to date using parse(), it is changing to Wed May 23 13:16:14 IST 2012.

That is not true, It converts back to `Date` correctly, When you try to print Date instance,  It invokes toString() method and it has fixed formated output so if you want the formatted date you need to use `format()` method

In short parse method parses the `String` to `Date` there is no property of `Date` which holds format so you need to use `format()` method *anyhow*

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
     String bookingDate = sdf.format(booking.getJourneyDate());here journey date is of date type when i do booking.setJourneyDate((Date)sdf.parse(bookingDate)); journey date is set to Wed May 23 00:00:00 IST 2012..?

Comment: What you are trying to say in comment ?

Comment: If i parse the string to date i am getting it as wed may 23. but i need to asign the formated date to the journeydate. is there a way to get the date in dd-mmm-yy format?

Comment: You need to use `format()` method that is the only option, Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing the date object in your query, if you are simply appending date in your query string why you need to convert your string date back to date object ? And If you are using prepared statement then you need not worry about the format. And as suggested above Date object does not hold any format information

Answer (score 0):

If You strictly need to pass the date object then there is no worries about its format as Date object has understanding with its format either Java, any java framework or SQL..

And if you are passing the date directly in sql query (concatenating) then you can pass Date String in the same format you see in DB, it will process the same correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, <locale>).parse(myDate);`.

You will, however, have a date in a standard format like dd/MM/yy, not custom. Template depends on which [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) you use.

You can try building your own Pattern using the standard Java Library or through [ThreeTen/JSR-310](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

We now have a more modern way to do this work.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is bundled with Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). These new classes are inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. They are a vast improvement over the troublesome confusing old classes, java.util.Date/.Calendar et al.

### Date-only class

The new framework offers a class, [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), to represent a date-only without any time-of-day nor time zone.

By the way, using two-digits for year is asking for trouble. I strongly recommend using four-digit years whenever possible. The java.time framework assumes any two-digit years are in the `20xx` century, years 2000 to 2099 inclusive.

To parse the string, specify the expected format. You are not using any of the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, so we must define a format pattern. Specify a Locale that includes the language we expect to find for name-of-month.

```
// Parse String representation.
String input = "23-May-12";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "d-MMMM-yy" , Locale.ENGLISH );  // Using four "M" characters means we expect the full name of the month.
LocalDate localDate = formatter.parse ( input , LocalDate :: from );
```

To go the other direction, to generate a string representation of the date value, we can recycle the same formatter.

```
    // Generate String representation.
    String output = localDate.format ( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
    System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " → localDate : " + localDate );
    System.out.println ( "localDate : " + localDate + " → output: " + output );
```

When run.

> input: 23-May-12 → localDate : 2012-05-23
>
> localDate : 2012-05-23 → output: 23-May-12