# How to change Date format type between dates?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

how to change this date type "Thu Feb 02 12:00:00 GMT-12:00 2012" to another date type "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"?
If "Thu Feb 02 12:00:00 GMT-12:00 2012" is the String type, how to convert Date type of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"?

java code:

```
DateFormat inputDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
   DateFormat outputDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date dd = inputDF.parse("Thu Feb 02 12:00:00 GMT-12:00 2012");
   String strDate = outputDF.format(dd);
```

The output is String type. I wanna get Date type output so I added following code.

```
   Date outputDate = outputDF.parse(strDate);
```

But I get again Date with this "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy" format. I want to get Date with this "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format and also want Date Type.

**I also want to get the output type is Date type format.**

Comment: First you need JVM to understand input format, look to Jigar Joshi's answer. and then you can translate it to any format you want

Answer (score 2):

```
DateFormat inputDF = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
        DateFormat outputDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(outputDF.format(inputDF.parse("Thu Feb 02 12:00:00 GMT-12:00 2012")));
```

Comment: I wanna the output format is also Date type. If I used like this outputDF.format(inputDF.parse(stringInstance)), output format is change to String. I do not want to get this type. I wanna get Date type output. How to do?

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731523/converting-date-to-string-and-back-to-date-in-java/10731552#10731552)

Comment: If you want Date type output, then just take `inputDF.parse(dateString)` and skip `outputDF`.

Comment: @shariphwar, did you even look for return values? Did you even read about methods in programming languages in general?

Comment: Yes, I also want to Date type output. I don't know how to do. Please explain me! Thanks!

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731523/converting-date-to-string-and-back-to-date-in-java/10731552#10731552

Comment: Didn't get you, could you please state your exact question here

Comment: I wanna insert Date to Database that column type is DateTime. I have a date that is "Thu Feb 02 12:00:00 GMT-12:00 2012". How do I insert this date to database? I used MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

## String != Date

Your main problem is in thinking of a string as a date. It is not. Consider that "$12.34" is not a number, it is a textual representation of a number and currency type formatted for presentation. So too do you have a textual representation of a date-time and time zone.

### String → Date-Time → String

So first step is parsing that string as a date-time object. Then use that date-time object to generate a *new* textual representation of its date-time value.

## java.time

You are using the old date-time classes from the earliest version of Java. These classes, while a valiant industry-first effort, have proven to be confusing and flawed. Avoid them.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### Formatter

We must specify a coded pattern to define a formatter with which we will parse your input strings. The codes are similar to the old java.text.SimpleDateFormat class but not exactly the same. So carefully study [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Note the use of `O` for `localized zone-offset`.

Note that on the formatter we use a second argument to specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). That Locale specifies the human language used to parse and translate the name of the month and day. If omitted the JVM’s current default Locale is used. That default can change at any moment, so I suggest always specifying the expected Locale.

```
String input = "Thu Feb 02 12:00:00 GMT-12:00 2012";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O yyyy" , Locale.ENGLISH );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt );
```

> 2012-02-02T12:00-12:00

That output is standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. I suggest using these standard formats where possible because of they are easy to read, unambiguous, and, well, standard.

The format you want is close to standard but replaces the `T` with a SPACE. And your format omits any [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or time zone. Omitting the time zone is risky as human readers may assume the wrong time zone. But if you insist, define such a pattern yourself.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
String output = zdt.format ( formatterOutput );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt + " output: " + output );
```

> zdt: 2012-02-02T12:00-12:00 output: 2012-02-02 12:00:00

Better yet, let java.time localize for you. Note how we call [`withLocale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale-java.util.Locale-) to give the formatter a Locale whose language will be used for the name of month and name of day.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterLocalized = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( FormatStyle.FULL );
formatterLocalized = formatterLocalized.withLocale ( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String outputLocalized = zdt.format ( formatterLocalized );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt + " output: " + output + " outputLocalized: " + outputLocalized );
```

> zdt: 2012-02-02T12:00-12:00 output: 2012-02-02 12:00:00 outputLocalized: jeudi 2 février 2012 12 h 00 -12:00

Answer (score 0):

```
String strDate = "Thu Feb 02 12:00:00 GMT-12:00 2012";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.format(strDate);

And to get the result in Date, You can use the following :

Date d = new Date(dateFormat.format(strDate));
```

Comment: I tested the Date with your code. Error occurred **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
 at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)**

Comment: Sorry.. tats because of the string given as date. Dateformat wont accept "Thu Feb".. so try this.
"02-02-2012 12:00"

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateStart = "Thu Feb 02 12:00:00 GMT-12:00 2012";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date d1 = format.parse(**dateStart**);
System.out.prinln("formatted date.." + d1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The `Date` object does not have a representation format. It only has the data. The formatter has the format. Formatting is used to display data.