# How to convert from Mon Sep 02 17:00:00 PDT 2019 to 09022019 in groovy?

Tags: date, groovy, date-formatting

I'm getting date format "Mon Sep 02 17:00:00 PDT 2019" from UI to process. But i want to convert as 09022019. Below code i tried but that convert to one day before.

```
sampleDate = Mon Sep 02 17:00:00 PDT 2019 
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy")
sdf.format(sampleDate)
```

I'm getting 09012019 but expected date is 09022019.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Date format type between dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796893/how-to-change-date-format-type-between-dates)

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. This topic has been addressed many many times already. Search for `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZonedDateTime` classes in *java.time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `setTimeZone` for `SimpleDateFormat`.

By default, SimpleDateFormat uses default timezone of system if none specified. It can be checked just by changing second line of you code to `sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy z")`. Perhaps it's why you getting *09012019*.

One more thing. `TimeZone.getTimeZone("PDT")` do not return timezone object for PDT. I guess because PDT is not a time zone but a pseudo-time zone. Then we will use something like `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")`.

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy")
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"))
sdf.format(sampleDate)
```

Will return 09022019 no matter of system timezone.

Comment: it's possible to get TimeZone from parsed date `SimpleDateFormat.getTimeZone()` to avoid hardcoded "PDT"

Comment: Sure, good advice. There possible to do:

`tz = ZonedDateTime.parse("Mon Sep 02 17:00:00 PDT 2019", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")).getZone()
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz))`

But I'm not certain that `sampleDate` in this example is string or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on Java 8+ and Groovy 2.5+, you can use the Java 8 Date/Time APIs:

```
import java.time.*
new Date("Mon Sep 02 17:00:00 PDT 2019").toZonedDateTime().format('MMddyyy')
```