# Convert a string to java.util.date AND preserve the timezone information

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat, java.util.date

*Before anybody downvotes this question, I have browsed the web and StackOverflow for the situation that I am facing and did not find anything, hence I am posting as a new question.*

I have a situation with java date and timezones.

**Situation:**

There are 2 servers on 2 different timezones, lets say PST and CST. I am receiving dateString(date as a string) from those servers. But, when I try to convert the string back to date, using SimpleDateFormat, the date information(Year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds) is being converted properly. But the timezone information is not being preserved.

If I run my code on a server in EST, the pstDateString is converted to Date format, but the Timezone is being set to EDT, instead of PST.

I thought about it in many different ways but may be that I am stressed, I am not able to find a solution. Any help ?

Code block that would simulate the situation :

```
        DateFormat outDF1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
        outDF1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));        
        String pstDateString = outDF1.format(new Date());

        DateFormat outDF2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
        outDF2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
        String cstDateString = outDF2.format(new Date());

        System.out.println("pstDateString "+pstDateString);
        System.out.println("cstDateString "+cstDateString);

        Date cstDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS").parse(cstDateString);
        Date pstDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS").parse(pstDateString);

        System.out.println("Date after format from string: "+pstDate);
        System.out.println("Date after format from string: "+cstDate);
```

Output Currently:

```
pstDateString 2012-06-07 10:26:689
cstDateString 2012-06-07 12:26:694
Date after format from string: Thu Jun 07 10:26:00 EDT 2012
Date after format from string: Thu Jun 07 12:26:00 EDT 2012
```

Output Expected:

```
pstDateString 2012-06-07 10:26:689
cstDateString 2012-06-07 12:26:694
Date after format from string: Thu Jun 07 10:26:00 PST 2012
Date after format from string: Thu Jun 07 12:26:00 CST 2012
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting date to string and back to date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731523/converting-date-to-string-and-back-to-date-in-java)

Comment: NO, it is not that situation.

Comment: You might want to look at the Joda time library which handles many combinations of date,time,timezone.  Or you could store all times in GMT and display whatever the user or interface prefers. i.e. the original time zone shouldn't matter.

Comment: By the way, seconds is a lowercase `s` in SimpleDateFormat - uppercase `S` is milliseconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the java.util.Date class has no timezone, it is always in UTC.  if you want to preserve the incoming timezone, you will need a new class which combines a Date and a TimeZone.  you could create a simple holder class, or possibly use a Calendar.

Comment: I was thinking more of creating a domain object with the dateString and the timezone information and passing that around. Is that a reasonable way of approach ?

Comment: sure, although i don't know why you would store the date as a String instead of a Date (which is essentially a long).

Comment: I wish I could change that ! The dev who did all this is on vacation, and I got this bug to fix :)

Comment: @codezilla - but, if you control the domain object (you are creating it after all), don't you have the option to choose Date or String?  if you hold as a String, you will need to re-parse each time before you format.

Comment: yes.. i am cleaning up all the unnecessary conversions and maintain a generic state