# How to resolve: java.sql.SQLException: setDate, Exception = Invalid year value

Tags: java, date, jpa, sqlexception

I have a simple TypedQuery, which selects datas from my DB:

```
TypedQuery<MyTable> query = entityManager.createQuery("select t from MyTable t where t.valueDate between :fromDate and :toDate ", MyTable.class);
query.setParameter("fromDate", fromDate, TemporalType.DATE);
query.setParameter("toDate", toDate, TemporalType.DATE);
List<MyTable> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

The **fromDate** and **toDate** are come from background. Sometimes I am getting this date: **0123-12-27T00:00:00.000+01:00**. This date is valid in my java app. But when I want to use this date in my query, it will throw an exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: setDate, Exception = Invalid year value

So the java.sql cannot set the date, because the year is **0123**.

Why is that? How can I check the validation of the year in java for sql, even if it is valid in java?

Should I check the year in java before the query? From which year is the date valid for java.sql?

Comment: Why not read the javadoc for that class (java.sql.Date)???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting date to string and back to date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731523/converting-date-to-string-and-back-to-date-in-java)

Comment: You can't use java.util.Date and java.sql.Date interchangeably. You will either have to work with java.sql.Date in your application, and pass that to your query as fromDate and toDate, or you will need to convert between the two, which will have its own set of issues.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 and later, the [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class has a new [`valueOf(LocalDate date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDate-) method. You can use it to create an sql date object with the date string **0123-12-27T00:00:00.000+01:00** and the following code snippet.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class SQLDateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Date d = java.sql.Date.valueOf(OffsetDateTime.parse("0123-12-27T00:00:00.000+01:00").toLocalDate());
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

The java.sql.Date is printed as **0123-12-27**. Note that the offset from UTC is not taken into account.